# How to do string semantic matching using gensim in Python?

Tags: python, string, string-matching, semantics

how can we determine whether a string has a semantical relation with our phrase or not in python?

**Example:**

our phrase is:

```py
'Fruit and Vegetables'
```

and the strings we want to check semantical relation in, are:

```py
'I have an apple in my basket', 'I have a car in my house'
```

**result:**

as we know the first item `I have an apple in my basket` has a relation to our phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gensim` library to implement `MatchSemantic` and write code like this as a function (**[see full code in here](https://gist.github.com/Amir-Shamsi/4e537cf83626726361209923b0d72fd6)**):

#### Initialization

---

1. install the `gensim` and `numpy`:

```
pip install numpy
pip install gensim
```

#### Code

---

1. first of all, we must implement the requirements

```py
from re import sub
import numpy as np
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess
import gensim.downloader as api
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary
from gensim.models import TfidfModel
from gensim.similarities import SparseTermSimilarityMatrix, WordEmbeddingSimilarityIndex, SoftCosineSimilarity
```

2. use this function to check if the strings and sentences match the phrase you want.

```py
def MatchSemantic(query_string, documents):
    stopwords = ['the', 'and', 'are', 'a']

    if len(documents) == 1: documents.append('')

    def preprocess(doc):
        # Tokenize, clean up input document string
        doc = sub(r'<img[^<>]+(>|$)', " image_token ", doc)
        doc = sub(r'<[^<>]+(>|$)', " ", doc)
        doc = sub(r'\[img_assist[^]]*?\]', " ", doc)
        doc = sub(r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', " url_token ", doc)
        return [token for token in simple_preprocess(doc, min_len=0, max_len=float("inf")) if token not in stopwords]

    # Preprocess the documents, including the query string
    corpus = [preprocess(document) for document in documents]
    query = preprocess(query_string)

    # Load the model: this is a big file, can take a while to download and open
    glove = api.load("glove-wiki-gigaword-50")
    similarity_index = WordEmbeddingSimilarityIndex(glove)

    # Build the term dictionary, TF-idf model
    dictionary = Dictionary(corpus + [query])
    tfidf = TfidfModel(dictionary=dictionary)

    # Create the term similarity matrix.
    similarity_matrix = SparseTermSimilarityMatrix(similarity_index, dictionary, tfidf)

    query_tf = tfidf[dictionary.doc2bow(query)]

    index = SoftCosineSimilarity(
        tfidf[[dictionary.doc2bow(document) for document in corpus]],
        similarity_matrix)

    return index[query_tf]
```

**Attention:**
if run the code for the first time a process bar will go from `0%` to `100%` for downloading `glove-wiki-gigaword-50` of the `gensim` and after that everything will be set and you can simply run the code.

#### Usage

---

for example, we want to see if `Fruit and Vegetables` matches any of the sentences or items inside `documents`

**Test:**

```py
query_string = 'Fruit and Vegetables'
documents = ['I have an apple on my basket', 'I have a car in my house']
MatchSemantic(query_string, documents)
```

---

so we know that the first item `I have an apple on my basket` has a semantical relation with `Fruit and Vegetables` so its score will be `0.189` and for the second item no relation will be found so its score will be `0`

**output:**

```py
0.189    # I have an apple in my basket
0.000    # I have a car in my house
```